# How do I simulate a network?

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I want to simulate the following network with 2 laptops connected over internet. How can I do it? How can I set up the intefaces? [I'm using KVM if it matters]. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of the simulation?
Do you want to see e.g. how the communication between two NATted networks
proceeds, are you interested in routing problems, or what else?

Comment: I want to collect some performance measurements of tunneling (OpenVPN and IPsec) with different encryption algorithms. I want to make it as realistic as possible.

Comment: Do you have a router, or are you trying to do this without one?

Comment: I just realized you attached a png image of an ascii art diagram.  Are you trying to break the internet?

Comment: I'm trying to do it without a router. Btw I actually wanted to make an ASCII art but it was not displayed properly so I took a screenshot of it :D. I did mention this in my original post but it was edited :).

Comment: You should have posted this as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @bonzi so, you have two different laptops, each with a VM?

Comment: Yes. Two different laptop connected via internet. And I'm running KVM in each of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using a router, just connect one laptop's NIC to the other's NIC, you'll need to use a crossover Cat 5 cable. BTW, that's not "The Internet", it's just wires with Ethernet on them.

Comment: You can also create an ad-hoc wireless netowork, as the two mentioned devices are laptops. Create the network on one laptop and have the other laptop connect to it.